docker compose run docker:dind ,The certificate was reset during restart
this is my docker-compose.yaml
services:
  jenkins-docker:
    image: docker:dind
    container_name: jenkins-docker
    privileged: true
    networks:
    networks:
      pipeline:
        aliases:
          - docker
    environment:
      DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: /certs
    volumes:
      #- docker-certs:/certs/client
      - ./certs:/certs/client
      - data:/var/jenkins_home
    ports:
      - "2376:2376"
    command: --storage-driver overlay2

  jenkins-blueocean:
    #image: jenkins-blueocean:2.440.3-1
    image: jenkins-blueocean:2.452.1-1
    container_name: jenkins-blueocean
    restart: on-failure
    #depends_on:
    #  - jenkins-docker
    networks:
      pipeline:
        aliases:
          - jenkins
    environment:
      DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2376
      DOCKER_CERT_PATH: /certs/client
      DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY: "1"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50000:50000"
    volumes:
      - data:/var/jenkins_home
      #- docker-certs:/certs/client:ro
      - ./certs:/certs/client:ro
networks:
  pipeline:
    external: true

volumes:
  #docker-certs:
  data:


The certificate was reset during restart, how to keep certs ? 
i'v try volumes and local path, but where i restart docker , the certs was new
the ca.pem cert.pem csr.pem openssl.conf is new, but key.pem is old
